Pending promise stored as property in object array, do not know how to access to fulfill
I'm trying to fill an array of objects with specific property values and am using Promises with async/await with Javascript in a Node.JS environment. Here is the main part:
getPublicNotes(connectHeaders, baseurl, pubKey, noteKeyList).then((nkl) => {
    if (nkl.length > 0) {
        getSecurityAbEntry(connectHeaders, baseurl, nkl);
        for (let count = 0; count < nkl.length; count++) {
            let secGroupKey = getSecurityAbEntry(connectHeaders, baseurl, nkl[count]);
            nkl[count].writeAccessKey = secGroupKey;
        }
    } else {
        console.log("EMPTY: There are no Public Notes; nothing to process.");
    }
    /* for (let count2 = 0; count2 < nkl.length; count2++) {
        let notesSecGroup = setNoteSecurity(connectHeaders, baseurl, nkl[count2]); 
        console.log(notesSecGroup);
    } */
});

noteKeyList is an array of objects, initially empty.
getPublicNotes(...noteKeyList) is an async function that returns an array of objects within a Promise.
getSecurityAbEntry(...nkl[count]) is an async function that takes in a single object and returns a single writeAccessKey value within a Promise. At the end of the for loop, the noteKeyList array looks like this:
[
{
abEntryKey: 'abc124der',
noteKey: '098ert'
writeAccessKey: Promise { <pending> }
},
{
abEntryKey: 'def321red',
noteKey: '392tkf'
writeAccessKey: Promise { <pending> }

},
{
abEntryKey: 'ghi645green',
noteKey: '9384fds'
writeAccessKey: Promise { <pending> }
},
...
]

How do I use then() to access each objects' writeAccessKey property?
The setNoteSecurity() is what I want to use next on each object in the array but don't know how to dig into each object in the array to feed into this async function.
Suggestions?
PS: I can give you the contents of each async function but I figure I'll start with this in case it's the functions' contents is not necessary.

Why is this tagged [async-await] if you're not using it? Why do you use .then() instead?

What is getSecurityAbEntry(connectHeaders, baseurl, nkl) doing? (And why are you not using its return value?) It's weird that you're calling the function once with an array as the third argument and then again with each array element as the argument.

You can use Promise.all() to wait for all the promises in an array to be resolved. It returns an array of all the resolved values.

I suspect that the code is hoping to obtain the fulfilled value of promises in synchronous code, not withstanding the obstacle that it  can't be done. If setNoteSecurity is truly an async function, its code could await the promise property of its argument object before using it, but bear in mind that its (setNoteSecurity 's) return value, shown in comments as assigned to notesSecGroup, will be a Promise object, rather than a fulfilled value if the promise is successful.

getSecurityAbEntry(connectHeaders, baseurl, nkl);  what is this call on line #3 supposed to be doing?

You'll want to map the nkl array to a new one where each getSecurityAbEntry() call has been resolved, then pass this to Promise.all() to wait for them all to resolve.
const notes = await getPublicNotes(connectHeaders, baseurl, pubKey, noteKeyList);

const finalList = await Promise.all(
  notes.map(async (note) => ({
    ...note,
    writeAccessKey: await getSecurityAbEntry(connectHeaders, baseurl, note),
  })),
);

console.log(finalList);


If you don't want to use async / await, then the equivalent looks like this
getPublicNotes(connectHeaders, baseurl, pubKey, noteKeyList)
  .then((notes) =>
    Promise.all(
      notes.map((note) =>
        getSecurityAbEntry(connectHeaders, baseurl, note).then(
          (writeAccessKey) => ({
            ...note,
            writeAccessKey,
          }),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
  .then((finalList) => {
    console.log(finalList);
  });


Thank you to everyone who contributed to answering my question. With my inexperience using async/await with promises, I didn't want to dig myself into a hole I couldn't get out of, so I decided to call the async function from within the for loop. This worked out. Thank you again everyone.
